# Maven project installing to jar, getting 404 trying to hit paths

Tags: java, spring, maven, facelets

Here is what is probably a really simple questions for the initiated (which I am not)

I have the following maven project, that seems like it should serve a static index.html that redirects to /entrance, which is mapped to a spring controller.  A facelet view should be served.

Unfortunately, I'm getting a 404 when I hit /index.html or /entrance.

In fact, index.html is not even in the generated jar. Neither is /pages, /css, /js, and /templates.

What gives?

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mydomain</groupId>
    <artifactId>webapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <start-class>com.mydomain.webapp.Application</start-class>
        <jsf.version>2.1.6</jsf.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RC3</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Faces -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSF -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jsf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${jsf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Facelets -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.facelets</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-facelets</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.14</version>
        </dependency>        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestone</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestone</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.svg</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.ttf</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.txt</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.woff</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

spring-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="cache" value="false" />
        <property name="viewClass" value="pl.cichon.andrzej.springmvcfacelets.common.mvc.FaceletView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".xhtml" />
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mydomain.webapp.mvc"/>
</beans>
```

faces-config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>  
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <application>
        <!-- JSF and Spring integration -->
        <el-resolver>
            org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
        </el-resolver>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

BaseController.java:

```
@Controller
public class BaseController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/entrance", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView entrance(Model model) {
        ModelMap map = new ModelMap();
        map.addAttribute("hello", "Hello, world!");
        return new ModelAndView("football_players", map);
    }

}
```

football_players.xhtml:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">


    <ui:composition template="/templates/maintemplate.xhtml">

        <ui:define name="title">${team} players:</ui:define>

        <ui:define name="content">
            <h1>${team}'s players:</h1>
            <ul>
                <ui:repeat var="player" value="${players}">
                    <li>${player}</li>
                </ui:repeat>
            </ul>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</html>
```

Project, as seen in netbeans:

```
Web Pages
  WEB-INF
    faces-config.xml
    spring-servlet.xml
    web.xml
  css
    yada yada.css
  js 
    yada yada.js
  pages
    football-players.xhtml
  templates
    maintemplate.xhtml
  index.html
```

Comment: does "Web Pages" actually mean the files are in src/main/webapp ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven doesn't know, that your application is a web-application. 
Add packaging type as war into your pom.xml:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

If you are not familiar enough with maven, try to generate web-app template via [archetype](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html): 
`mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-webapp -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp`